# Allow user to cancel upload javascript, xmlhttp request

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have an xmlhttprequest that is posting to a webservice and is linked to the user uploading a potentially large file and I would like to be able to cancel the request based on user input.  I see that the xmlhttprequest object has an abort function but as far as I can tell by watching the network tab in chrome, calling that does not actually stop sending data and free up the users bandwidth, it only affects the events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would use jquery here:

```
var xhr = $.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "x.php",
success: function(msg){
}
});

//kill the request
xhr.abort()
```

Comment: Do you know exactly how jqueries abort differs from the standard xmlhttprequest abort function and if it actually stops sending data?

Comment: it shouldnt make a difference. you might be sending the ajax request synchronously (not asynchronously) in which case you wouldnt be able to abort it.

Comment: hmm, I am reasonably sure I am sending it asynchronous as my UI continues to function and I have set the third argument of my call to open to true, ie: "iafReq.open(type, url, true);"

Comment: One caveat to bear in mind: if the server has already received the request, it may continue processing the request even though the browser no longer listens for a response. There is no reliable way to make the web server stop processing a request that has already begun.

Comment: Ian, what exactly do you mean by "processing".  I don't care if the server continues executing code server side but I DO want the client to stop sending data.  Basically I want the equivilent of if the user say went to a different page mid upload.

Comment: he is saying that perhaps the data has already been sent to the server by the time you abort the request, in which case, there is no request to abort on the client side anymore